# Python Pandas read_excel doesn't recognize null cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas, nan

My excel sheet:

```
   A   B  
1 first second
2
3 
4  x   y  
5  z   j
```

Python code:

```
df = pd.read_excel (filename, parse_cols=1)
```

return a correct output:

```
  first second
0 NaN   NaN
1 NaN   NaN
2 x     y
3 z     j
```

If i want work only with second column

```
df = pd.read_excel (filename, parse_cols=[1])
```

return:

```
 second
0  y
1  j
```

I'd have information about empty excel rows (NaN in my df) even if I work only with a specific column.
If output loose NaN information  it's not ok, for example, for skiprows paramater, etc

Thanks

Comment: Do you try parameter `skip_blank_lines=False` ?

Comment: It works. Why I cannot see this parameter here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me works parameter `skip_blank_lines=False`:

```
df = pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx', 
                     parse_cols=1, 
                     skip_blank_lines=False)
print (df)

       A       B
0  first  second
1    NaN     NaN
2    NaN     NaN
3      x       y
4      z       j
```

Or if need omit first row:

```
df = pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx', 
                     parse_cols=1, 
                     skiprows=1,
                     skip_blank_lines=False)
print (df)

  first second
0   NaN    NaN
1   NaN    NaN
2     x      y
3     z      j
```

Comment: Yes it works. But why I don't see this parameter in the official documentation?  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: See `General Parsing Configuration` in [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table), or this parameter is in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: In official docs -  [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) it is behind  `**kwds` ;(

Comment: I try omit it `df = pd.read_excel ('test.xlsx', 
                         parse_cols=1, 
                         skiprows=1)` and with my test data it works too - I use pandas `0.18.1`

Comment: In pandas 1.1.4: `TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines'` and no mention in the documentation posted above.