# Pandas read_excel removes columns under empty header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have an Excel file where A1,A2,A3 are empty but A4:A53 contains column names.

In "R" when you were to read that data, the columns names for A1,A2,A3 would be "X_1,X_2,X_3" but when using `pandas.read_excel` it simply skips the first three columns, thus ignoring them. The problem is that the number of columns in each file is dynamic thus I cannot parse the column range, and I cannot edit the files and adding "dummy names" for A1,A2,A3

Comment: Just to check, do you mean columns or rows that are skipped? Is there data in columns B and other columns? Can you maybe provide an example?

Comment: It is columns which are skipped.
I tried to make a small example, but I cannot format code ( it seems like).
I just figured out, that what happen is the first three columns are merged into an index

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter skip_blank_lines=False, like so:

```
pd.read_excel('your_excel.xlsx', header=None, skip_blank_lines=False)
```

This stackoverflow question (finally) pointed me in the right direction:
[Python Pandas read_excel doesn't recognize null cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334543/python-pandas-read-excel-doesnt-recognize-null-cell)

The [pandas.read_excel docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) don't contain any info about this since it is one of the keywords, but you can find it in the general io docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table

Comment: It does not work - it still ignores the first three columns

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to pass `header=None` to pandas' `read_excel()` function, manually insert the missing values into the first row (it now will contain the column names), then assign that row to `df.columns` and drop it after. Not the most elegant way, but I don't know of a builtin solution to your problem

EDIT: by "manually insert" I mean some messing with `fillna()`, since this appears to be an automated process of some sort

Comment: Actually that is a good idea! I wont ping it as answer, since it is not an answer to the problem, but solves the issue (and acutally made some things nice!).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, but I solved it by specifying the column names and naming the final empty column, rather than importing with no names and then having to deal with a row with names in it (also used use_cols).  See below:

```
use_cols = 'A:L'

column_names = ['Col Name1', 'Col Name 2', 'Empty Col']

df = pd.read_excel(self._input_path, usecols=use_cols, names=column_names)
```