# Don't skip blank lines in pandas.read_excel()

Tags: python, excel, pandas

According to multiple sources on SO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53615545/pandas-read-excel-removes-columns-under-empty-header), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39334543/python-pandas-read-excel-doesnt-recognize-null-cell), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47577016/reading-in-empty-cells-with-read-excel-in-python-pandas)), the `pandas` method `read_excel()` has the option `skip_blank_lines` to control whether `pandas` parses blank rows in an excel file as blank rows in a `DataFrame`. However, the current [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) does not mention this. Has it been deprecated? If so, when, and, most importantly, how can I replicate the effect of `skip_blank_lines=False` without it?

Comment: I've tested it on pandas 0.24.1 and still works. It seems like an undocumented feature.

Comment: Relevant discussion - https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/39808

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This method has not been deprecated as of the latest release, and I don't know of any intentions to deprecate it (0.24.1 does not produce a future warning when using this method).

As to why it's not documented on the `read_excel` page, I believe it's because `skip_blank_lines=False` is passed as a keyword argument to `TextFileReader` (which is hinted at in the documentation).

Comment: In pandas 1.1.4: `read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'skip_blank_lines'`